# flutter Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget, how to find the place where the error is?

Tags: flutter

I have an error `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget`, but the place in the code where it is located is unknown. I tried to use `Flutter DevTools`, but there is nothing there either. How can I find where the problem is? The place where the error occurs, I found out approximately through the breakpoints, but there is nowhere `Column ← Expanded ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#70e68]` The error shows that the exception is triggered inside the `flutter framework`, but where exactly in the code the exception is triggered is not clear. How can you find the problem in this case? Usually the error says, in such a file and on which line the problem is, but here it is just an exception and the place where it is triggered is unknown I will be glad to any ideas

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a _SingleChildViewport widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  Column ← Expanded ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#70e68] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#9a817] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5991:11)
#1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6008:6)
#2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6031:36)
#3      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5677:5)
#4      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6525:11)
...     Normal element mounting (91 frames)
#95     SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (19 frames)
#114    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#115    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6518:36)
#116    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6531:32)
...     Normal element mounting (261 frames)
#377    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#378    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6518:36)
#379    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6531:32)
...     Normal element mounting (60 frames)
#439    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#440    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6518:36)
#441    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6531:32)
...     Normal element mounting (34 frames)
#475    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#476    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6518:36)
#477    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6531:32)
...     Normal element mounting (269 frames)
#746    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#747    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6518:36)
#748    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6531:32)
...     Normal element mounting (356 frames)
#1104   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#1105   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3500:18)
#1106   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:16)
#1107   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495:11)
#1108   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4463:5)
#1109   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4757:5)
#1110   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4752:5)
#1111   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:395:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1118   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1125   _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
#1126   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#1127   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3500:18)
#1128   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:16)
#1129   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495:11)
#1130   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4463:5)
#1131   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4757:5)
#1132   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4752:5)
#1133   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:395:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1140   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1147   _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
#1148   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#1149   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3500:18)
#1150   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:16)
#1151   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495:11)
#1152   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4463:5)
#1153   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4757:5)
#1154   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4752:5)
#1155   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:395:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1162   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1169   _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
#1170   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#1171   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3500:18)
#1172   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:16)
#1173   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495:11)
#1174   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4463:5)
#1175   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4757:5)
#1176   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4752:5)
#1177   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:395:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1184   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1191   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1198   _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
#1199   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#1200   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3500:18)
#1201   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:16)
#1202   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495:11)
#1203   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4463:5)
#1204   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4757:5)
#1205   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4752:5)
#1206   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:395:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1213   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1220   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1227   _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
#1228   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#1229   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3500:18)
#1230   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:16)
#1231   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495:11)
#1232   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4463:5)
#1233   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4757:5)
#1234   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4752:5)
#1235   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:395:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1242   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1249   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1256   _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
#1257   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#1258   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3500:18)
#1259   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:16)
#1260   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495:11)
#1261   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4463:5)
#1262   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4757:5)
#1263   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4752:5)
#1264   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:395:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1271   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1278   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1285   _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
#1286   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#1287   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3500:18)
#1288   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:16)
#1289   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495:11)
#1290   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4463:5)
#1291   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4757:5)
#1292   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4752:5)
#1293   _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:395:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1300   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1307   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1314   _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1321   SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#1328   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3756:14)
#1329   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3500:18)
#1330   RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1198:16)
#1331   RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1167:5)
#1332   RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1112:18)
#1333   BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2604:19)
#1334   RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111:13)
#1335   WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:944:7)
#1336   WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:924:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the last eight entries in that list are created by `SingleChildScrollView`, so all you can really get from that error message is

```
Column ← Expanded ← SingleChildScrollView
```

To find exactly where the widget was created, you can set a breakpoint on the line in the Flutter framework that throws the exception.  Once you reach that line, you can look at `this._widget._location` and `parentDataWidget._location`, which contain the same information that is used to display the relevant error-causing widget in other error messages.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have VS Code, and in the debugger, in the `Localas` -> parentDataWidget section, it points to the file and even the line in which the exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Flexible(), Expanded(), Flex() Widget` inside `Rows And Columns` , please check if you have placed it in other than rows and columns.
Try Searching Flex, Flexible, Expanded in your screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer questions without seeing the code.
but I think you are using the Expanded widget inside the incorrect parent Widget.
you have to use the Expanded widget only inside Row, Column or Flex widget. So that is can use the available space it the parent widget.
u can also [read the documentation](https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my machine on Flutter 2.12. Please provide the relevant code and output of Flutter doctor. Also check if you are using `Expanded` as a child of `Row`,`Column` or `Flex`.
Here's an example of how to use `Expanded` widget in a `Column`:

```
Column(
      children: const <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "This is an expanded box",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28
                ),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ]
  ),
)
```

[Click here to see the output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjTa0.png)